# How to turn-on a radio button programmatically

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I have the below posted radio button and input. I want to toggle the radio button programmatically so that, when I set `this.iAreaOfCoverageForThresholdPasser.average-height` to `true`, the radio button should be turned on "highlighted".

**HTML**:

```
<div id="idRadioButtonForAverageHeightDivision">
  <input [value]="1" [(ngModel)]="iOperationPasser.averageHeight" name="radioGroupForOperations" type="radio" clrCheckbox  (change)="onAverageHeightOptionSelected($event)"  [(checked)]="averageHeight"/>
  <label id="operation-average-height">
    {{ "SITE.AREAS_OF_COVERAGE_FOR_THRESHOLD.OPERATION_AVERAGE_HEIGHT" | translate }} 
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-icon" (click)="showInformation('SERVICE_DIST_4_AGRI')">
       <clr-icon shape="help-info" class="is-solid"></clr-icon>
    </button>
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: `average-height` is not a valid identifier.

Comment: @Dai would you please tell me why?i dont get any error related to this issue

Answer (score 0):

.html:

```
<div id="idRadioButtonForAverageHeightDivision">
 <input [value]="1"
        name="radioGroupForOperations"
        type="radio" 
        clrCheckbox
        (change)="onAverageHeightOptionSelected($event)"  
        [(checked)]="iOperationPasser.averageHeight"
 />

 <label id="operation-average-height">
 <button class="btn btn-sm btn-icon" (click)="onClick()">
  press
 </button>
 </label>
</div>
```

.ts

```
iOperationPasser = {
 averageHeight: true
}

onClick = () => {


this.iOperationPasser.averageHeight=!this.iOperationPasser.averageHeight;
}
```